# Объясните чем плох вотакойдомен.com

Tags: домен

Объясните чем плох вотакойдомен.com и почему при копировании доменного имени из поисковой строки получается http://xn--80adtafk4b.com/

Comment: А почему вы решили, что "плох"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Домен на кириллице – минусы**

Первый неприятный момент, который приносят кириллические домены – проблемы с кодировкой. Для корректного восприятия большинством интернет-сервисов и соответствия стандартам Unicode  приходится в обязательном порядке применять декодирование к доменам на кириллице. Для этого используется специальный метод преобразования символов под названием Punycode.

Получается, что красивый адрес МойСуперСайт.укр является лишь визуальным отображением реального xn--80ajlclmijgdnf.xn--j1amh. Именно так его и воспринимают поисковые системы и при этом не считают его человекопонятным урлом (ЧПУ).

Кроме того, конвертированный вариант нужно использовать везде при работе над сайтом. Например, для правильной настройки robots.txt.